# Cancel git merge after git commit

Tags: git, github

I made some changes on my branch, I fetched changes and ran 'git merge'. I then made more local changes and wanted to amend my commit: git commit --amend.
But when trying to push I received that error:

```
remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/v1.
remote: error: This branch must not contain merge commits.

 ! [remote rejected]   v1 -> v1 (protected branch hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to xxx
```

I tried to abort but:

```
git merge --abort
fatal: There is no merge to abort (MERGE_HEAD missing).
```

How can I cancel the merge commit without losing my local changes?

Comment: You can't cancel a merge if there is no (ongoing) merge. There are also no local changes to loose, you just can't push your local changes as the remote refuses to accept them. Consult the documentation of the project as this has likely been done for a reason. v1 suggests that this is related to release management of the software, so talk with the release manager what the shared knowledge is about that situation. In general rebase on the remotes v1 top (without preserving merges) but you should better understand your teams workflow, this sounds more like a social problem.

Comment: And _GH006_ suggests that is on Microsofts' Github. Just push to a different remote branch (e.g. `git push origin v1:v1-merge-patch`), then file a pull request against v1 and @ping the relevants.

Comment: My last comment may even make most sense: You either have the rights to fast-forward merge into v1, so the pull request should offer a rebase option and therefore you can even get your changes into v1, or it does not then you can still @ping or request a review and document the known solution for the problem. As its Friday, sanity suggests to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to cancel the merge by cancelling the commit, and to keep my local changes by doing:

`git reset --soft HEAD~1`

Comment: If it was the last one, this could work. Next time fetch and rebase (not fetch + merge). Contact your lead how to configure your local development system thought, as when there are such rules, the configuration should reflect them (e.g. rebase on pull).

Comment: The merge's changes would also be included when you do a git reset with `--soft` to before the merge commit.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a new branch because the following steps could delete some of your changes permanently. Also create a backup of your directory just in case.

First checkout a new branch from your current one, e.g. `git checkout -b my-new-branch`.

Then hard set your branch to your last commit on your branch before you merged in the other branch: `git reset --hard <last commit reference, e.g. 134124124124>`.

Then you could cherry pick any commits you made on your old branch after the merge commit, e.g. `git cherry-pick 123123123`.